# Puzzle from an Interview with Eric Lippert: Inheritance and Generic Type Setting

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Can someone explain to me why the below code outputs what it does?
Why is T a String in the first one, not an Int32, and why is it the opposite case in the next output?

This puzzle is from an [interview with Eric Lippert](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1292/eric-lippert-interview)

When I look through the code, I really have no idea if it's going to be an Int32 or a String:

```
public class A<T>
    {
        public class B : A<int>
        {
            public void M() { System.Console.WriteLine(typeof(T)); }
            public class C : B { }
        }
    }

    public class P
    {
        public static void Main()
        {            
            (new A<string>.B()).M(); //Outputs System.String
            (new A<string>.B.C()).M(); //Outputs System.Int32
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the code slightly:

```
public class A<T>
{
    public class B : A<int>
    {
        public void M() { System.Console.WriteLine(typeof(T)); }
        public class C : A<T>.B { }
    }
}

public class P
{
    public static void Main()
    {            
        (new A<string>.B.C()).M(); //Outputs System.String
    }
}
```

Note how I changed `C`'s base class from `B` to `A<T>.B`. This changes the output from `System.Int32` to `System.String`.

Without that, `A<string>.B.C` derives not from `A<string>.B`, but from `A<int>.B`, causing the behaviour you've seen. That's because in general, names defined in base classes are available by unqualified lookup, and the name `B` is defined in the base class `A<int>`.

Comment: Is it true to say that a class can access the inputted T value if it's no more than one "level" away from it? Eg. (new A<string>.B()).M(); outputs String because B is accessed directly after A<String> meaning the T supplied overrides the value that B inherits from by default? Whereas (new A<string>.B.C()).M(); outputs Int32 because once in C, it  is now 2 levels away from the inputted T value of String, and it therefore uses the default inherited value of Int32.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave No, that's not true, and putting `M`'s definition into `C` would show that it is not true. `A<T>.B.M` is going to print `T`, no matter how many levels away from it you are when you call it. The tricky part is only that `A<int>.B.M` is getting called rather than `A<string>.B.M`, due to the misleading base class.

Comment: Let me try and explain it again. If T flows downwards through the inheritance, it will override any default T values defined in the inheritance. However, as soon as there is a flow "upwards", in this case, when C calls M() which is defined in C's parent class, then the specified T value is lost and the default T value of Int32 is used. Whereas if M() was declared in C rather than B, then there would be no upward flow. Not entirely sure what words to use here, maybe "flow" isn't very good but I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave That's not what happens. `T` isn't being overridden. Inside `A<X>.B.C`, `T` would be `X`, without regard to `B`'s base class. `A<string>.B.C.M` is `A<int>.B.M`, not because `T` doesn't have the value you might expect, but because the base class `B` isn't the type you might expect. For `A<int>.B`, it's clear that `T` should be `int`, and it is.

Comment: Why is the base class B not the type that I might expect?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave That's specifically what I put in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

> Can someone explain to me why the below code outputs what it does?

I'll explain briefly here; a longer explanation can be found [here](https://ericlippert.com/2007/07/27/an-inheritance-puzzle-part-one/).

The crux of the matter is determining the meaning of `B` in `class C : B`. Consider a version without generics: (for brevity I'll omit the publics.)

```
class D { class E {} }
class J {
  class E {}
  class K : D {
    E e; // Fully qualify this type
  }
}
```

That could be `J.E` or `D.E`; which is it? The rule in C# when resolving a name is to look at the base class hierarchy, and only if that fails, then look at your container. K already has a member E by inheritance, so it does not need to look at its container to discover that its container has a member E by containment.

But we see that the puzzle has this same structure; it's just obfuscated by the generics.  We can treat the generic like a template and just write out the constructions of A-of-string and A-of-int as classes:

```
class A_of_int 
{
  class B : A_of_int
  {
    void M() { Write("int"); }
    class C : B { } // A_of_int.B
  }
}
class A_of_string
{
  class B : A_of_int
  {
    void M() { Write("string"); }
    class C : B {} // still A_of_int.B
  }
}
```

And now it should be clear why `A_of_string.B.M()` writes `string` but `A_of_string.B.C.M()` writes `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Method `M` inside `B` prints `typeof(T)` of `A<T>`, `A` is parent class of `B`.

So irrespective of whether `B` is derived from whatever, `M` prints `typeof(T)` that is `String`.

So `A<T>.B.M` prints nearest `A`'s `T`.

So `A<string>.B.M` will print `string`

Now, let us expand expression `A<string>.B.C`, which is equivalent to `A<string>.B.A<int>.B` (since `C` is `A<int>.B`), so method `A<string>.B.A<int>.B.M` will print nearest `T`.

`A<string>.B.A<int>.B.M` will print `int`

Comment: Why is C equal to A<int>.B? More precisely, why does the inputted value T which is String get lost, and the default value of Int is used?

Comment: It isn't equal to, it is how type resolution substitute types to resolve types.

Answer (score 3):

By the [Introduction to Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) T is also available in nested class. That is case with class `B` which is nested into `A`. On the other hand `C` is nested into `B` and T of the `B` is available into `C`. As you can see T of the `B` is `int` and method called on `C` will use `int` as generic parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Method `M()` Always prints type of generic parameter of the parent class of its class:

So `(new A<string>.B.C()).M();` should print generic type of `B` which is always `int`. (You can see `B` is always `A<int>`)

Also `(new A<string>.B()).M();` should print `string` because parent of `B` is `A<string>`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I didn't see the output I could guess the output correctly at first glance, but after seeing the result it's not too hard to detect how the result is printed. Chu puzzle is easy to solve patrol ;)